# Detecting position within a circle

Tags: java, mathematics

I need to detect the position of a knob on a touchpad. I need to detect if it is in particular areas and if so, which one. The sections, of course, being the colored parts.

[image: Touchpad]

I know that the black center circle ends at 0.8f and -0.8f for both the X and Y axis.

The information I can get is the percent X and percent Y which is 0 to 1 from center or 0 to -1 from center the other way.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what the arc tangent function of 2 arguments ([Math.atan2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2(double,%20double))) does.

```
double angle = Math.atan2(y, x);
```

Also, a common trick used to cheaply test the radius is:

```
double radius = 0.8;
if (x*x + y*y > radius*radius) {
    // outside the grey circle
}
```

Comment: There, I've added a common optimization, do I deserve an upvote yet?

Comment: I did upvote, it just says it doesnt show since Im new. I did accept it though.

Comment: lol my bad, didn't even check

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates).

The dark central circle is the set of points

```
C = { (r, phi) | 0 <= r <= 0.8, 0 <= phi < 2 pi }
```

The other coloured parts are the sets

`C_i = { (r, phi) | 0.8 <= r <= 1, phi_i <= phi < phi_(i+1) }`

where `i in {0,..,5}`, `phi_6 = phi_0` and you need to measure the angles `phi_i` from your diagram.

For the conversion between polar and Cartesian coordinates use the formulas from the linked Wikipedia article.